# TFS 2017 Release triggered after a while

Tags: tfs

We have a TFS CI build which builds successfully but the release does not trigger automatically but instead, it triggers after a while. all the settings look correct.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what do you mean "after a while"? how much time? can you share your release settings?

Comment: You need to provide more information, such as your configuration and observations.

Comment: sometimes it takes an hour and sometimes 2 to 3 hours for release to kick off.

Comment: Release trigger is set to Continous deployment, set trigger on artifact source set to build and for right branch. build also has CI trigger checked.

Comment: How many concurrent pipelines do you have? How many agents? Are you sure the release isn't queued up while other things are running?

Comment: We have 1 pipeline and 2 agents. we thought about that too but then we tested it when nothing else was running and still the same issue. We tested it again fri with a agent that is only handling this request and it took about 2 hours for the release kick off.

Comment: does this concurrent pipeline functionality works on TFS 2017 version? We have on prem version of TFS.